# Unable to setcookie() when SSI-include a PHP header file

Tags: php, ssi

Really lost here on what to do next. Lets say, I have

header.php

```
<?php 
    setcookie("the_cookie","data",time()+60); 
?>
    //followed by HTML codes
```

index.htm

```
<!--#include file="header.php"-->
<html>
      //standard html stuff here
</html>
```

When I include header.php in any of my html file, it fails to set cookie. This is despite

```
<!--#include file="header.php"-->
```

it being the very first line on my html document and setcookie being the very first line of the header.php The Apache server is SSI enabled. So I am certain the #include works as I have other HTML codes after the setcookie() function , and it shows correctly.

But when I run header.php itself, the cookie is set correctly. Has anyone here has ran into such situations before and knows what needs to be done?

Thank you in advanced

Gary Cho

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by using $_SESSION[] instead of setcookie(). Another benefit is that you can use also echo $_SESSION[] in the same php run that you set your $_SESSION[] value. I hope it works for you as well.